# how can i literaly read in C# a xml node with multiple atributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlreader

For a college project i was recently assigned i need to create a hotel system data managment WEB Aplication in C#  so one of many functions that it have its got from a xml file all the data that is going to save it in a sql data base, so in the xml file i got multiple nodes that means data of specific tables en the SQL database like:

```
<Cadena>
<Codigo> CA001 </Codigo>
...
</Cadena>
```

ok that isnt my problem, my problem and question is that what can i read a node like this:

```
<TipoHabitacion Cadena="CA001" Hotel="GT001">
.....
</TipoHabitacion>
```

i mean, i known that the table is "TipoHabitacion" and the Foreign Keys for that table are  "Cadena=CA001" and "Hotel=GT001" with those values, how can i differentiate that information knowing that in the same document is the same but with different foreign key like:

```
<TipoHabitacion Cadena="CA051" Hotel="GT781">
.....
</TipoHabitacion>
```

and save it with those new values?

Comment: I assume the "," separators between attributes is a translation fail when copying into StackOverflow? Otherwise, you're not working with XML at all...

Comment: maybe, but you are saying that "cadena" and "Hotel" are atributes of the xml noce "TipoHabitacion"?

Comment: you could try XML to LINQ to query nodes by its Attibute values, Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891206/parse-xml-with-linq-to-get-child-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to get the attributes of your elements? If so, this is a null-safe solution:

```
string cadenaValue = null;
string hotelValue = null;
if (node.Attributes != null)
{
    var cadenaAttribute = node.Attributes["Cadena"];
    if (cadenaAttribute != null) 
        cadenaValue = cadenaAttribute.Value;

    var hotelAttribute = node.Attributs["Hotel"];
    if (hotelAttribute != null)
        hotelValue = hotelAttribute.Value;
}

if (cadenaValue != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cadenaValue);
}

if (hotelValue != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(hotelValue);
}
```