# select Inner XML nodes which contains nearly same id

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

This is my XML..

```
<rootparent>
  <root>
    ...other nodes here.
    ...
    <parent>
      <child id="child_1">
        .some other nodes ..
      </child>  
      <child id="child_2">
        .some other nodes ..
      </child>  
      ...other nodes
    </parent>
  </root>
</rootparent>
```

I need to `select all the child nodes where id like 'child_%'` using LINQ to XML.

I got the xpath for this

```
string xPath="/root/parent/child[id='child_*']";
var x1 =xml.XPathSelectElement(xPath);
var x2 = _sourceDoc.Root.XPathEvaluate(xPath);
```

but it returns `Enumeration yielded no results`.

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891206/parse-xml-with-linq-to-get-child-elements

Comment: I need to use the XPath, i trying to make it generic.@Asnivor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
string xml =
    "<rootparent>" +
        "<root>" +
         "<parent>" +
          "<child id=\"child_1\">" +
          "</child>" +
          "<child id=\"child_2\">" +
          "</child>" +
         "</parent" +
        "</root>" +
    "</rootparent>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

List<XElement> children = doc.Descendants("child")
    .Where(x => ((string)x.Attribute("id")).StartsWith("child_"))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You are not using the XPath here, i need to utilize the XPath cause i'm trying to do it in more generic way.

Comment: If you want a generic solution you can still use linq xml.  Just use doc.Descendants() instead of specifying "child".  The title of the posting said Linq,

Comment: @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter: If you're not going to accept a linq solution, don't tag it as such. It's tagged as linq-to-xml so you got a linq-to-xml answer.

Comment: did you use XPath in your code, i need to used that.
i don't want to break XPAth one by one and find the node.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your xpath doesn't match the structure of your XML.  Your query assumes the root is called `root` but there's a `rootparent` and you don't account for it.  Since you're just looking for `child` nodes, you don't even need to reference it, just go through the descendants.

You need to use the appropriate condition.  None of your children contains an id element named `child_*` so naturally you won't get any results. Use the `starts-with` function and access the `id` *attribute*.

```
//child[starts-with(@id, 'child_')]
```